# Cloudformation: Reference created ACM Certificate in other region

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Since https certificates for Cloudfront can only be created in `us-east-1` and my entire stack is created in `eu-west-1` I wanted to create a stack in `us-east-1` that contains the ACM certificate, and then use that certificate in my stack(s) in `eu-west-1`.

The only problem is, how do I reference this certificate without hardcoding it, as I can't `ImportValue` an output in another region.

e.g.

```
  Distribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !GetAtt S3Bucket.RegionalDomainName
            Id: ****
            CustomOriginConfig:
              HTTPPort: '80'
              HTTPSPort: '443'
              OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
        DefaultRootObject: 'index.html'
        Enabled: true
        Aliases:
          - 'bla.bla.com'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          TargetOriginId: '*-origin'
          AllowedMethods:
          - GET
          - HEAD
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          CachePolicyId: '658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6'
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !ImportValue ****
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```

What do I need to put on the `AcmCertificateArn` line when I deploy this in `eu-west-1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've pointed out, you can't make cross-region export/import references between stacks in different regions. In this case, usually you would provide the Certificate ARN as an **input parameter** to your stack in `eu-west-1`.

The other options would involve the use of [SSM parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm) dynamic references to pass the value of the certificate's ARN. For **fully automated solution**, you would need to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in `eu-west-1` in the form of a lambda function. The function would query the stack in `us-east-1` for the arn in its outputs and return the arn to the stack in `eu-west-1`.

Comment: I saw that SSM parameter trick somewhere, but it's really a lot of stuff to put in place for something silly like this. I decided to use an input parameter. 
Pity AWS hasn't come up with a simple solution for this.